# Existing .ko file update to work with newer kernel?

Tags: linux, binary

I have a binary `.ko` driver file that I don't have source for.  Can I somehow use that `.ko` file with a newer kernel version?

For example, recompile to add kernel header to it?

Comment: No, you can't, unless you're pretty certain that it's 100% binary compatible with the newer kernel. Which you can't be if you don't even have the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Linux kernel checks the module version against the currently running kernel version and if they are different it will refuse to load the module.

You can probably use `hexedit` or even `sed` to correct the module version but as it's mentioned in the comment above there's zero guarantee the module will work with a different Linux release.

The status quo is:

- If your module version is `5.X.{???}`, it will most likely work with any `5.X.{???}` kernel
- If your module version is `5.X.{???}`, it's **highly** unlikely it will work with a kernel release `5.Y.{???}`

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/stable-api-nonsense.rst